# Hypothesis strategies for pydantic nested classes

Tags: python, pydantic, hypothesis-test

For our API, I started using hypothesis on top pydantic, in order to enhance test test suite with autogenerated data.
Our protocol is hierarchical, so comes easy to me to describe it with nested classes in pydantic:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, conint
from hypothesis import given, strategies as st

class Inner(BaseModel):
    start: conint(ge=0, le=9) = Field(description="starting value")
    end: conint(ge=0, le=9) = Field(description="it should be greater than start")


class Outer(BaseModel):
    inner: Inner = Field(description="I level class")

@given(st.builds(Outer))
def test_shema(schema):
    assert schema.inner.start <= schema.inner.end, "Nope!"


test_shema()
```

All works as expected, but I'm trying to enrich the semantic with some strategies, for example a rule between  `inner.start` and `inner.end`. In this example one should be greater.

**tentative I:**

Generate values in separate ranges:

```
roles = {'inner.start':st.integers(max_value=5), 'inner.end':st.integers(min_value=5)}
@given(st.builds(Outer, **roles))
```

For this approach I'm not able to specify the field in the inner dataclass, this solution simply doesn't work. Tried nested dicts, dotted notation.

**tentative II:**
Apply a correction to generated test function like this, but only in the test function:

```
if schema.inner.start >= schema.inner.end:
    schema.inner.start ,schema.inner.end = schema.inner.end ,schema.inner.start
```

This can be a valid approach, but how to describe it to hypothesis?

Starting from official [documentation](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#composite-strategies) I cannot find how to
define strategies for nested classes or put together the [composite](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#composite-strategies)  in order to apply some logic to the generated schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```python
@given(
    st.builds(
        Outer,
        inner=st.builds(
            Inner,
            start=st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=5),
            end=st.integers(min_value=5, max_value=9),
        ),
    )
)
```

[The documentation](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.builds) shows that you can use a strategy for an `arg` or `kwarg` of `builds()`:

> e.g. `builds(target, integers(), flag=booleans())` would draw an integer `i` and a boolean `b` and call `target(i, flag=b)`.

So, you could use the `builds()` strategy to provide the `inner` `kwarg` (pydantic expects `kwargs` in the `__init__()`), and use a similar approach to customize the `start` and `end` with the `integers()` strategy.

It seems that you need to provide both `min_value` and `max_value` in your scenario because the `integers()` strategy can generate integers outside the `ge` and `le`. I guess it is because `integers()` cannot know that its values will be used to feed the `start` and `end` fields, which seems acceptable to me.